# How to make a jQuery Dialog appear above Silverlight without using windowless

Tags: silverlight, jquery-ui

I am using a [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) in a web application that uses Silverlight on several pages.  When the dialog appears on pages with a SL window, the dialog is hidden behind the SL.  **I cannot use windowless mode.**  Is there any straight-forward way to make this dialog appear in front of SL?

Comment: I've been having the same problem but with Java applets.  I'd love to hear a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work fine using an iframe doing similar to what you explained with the floating div.

It might needs tweaking, but hopefully this can help others.

On your page, include an iframe like so:

```
<div id="popupDiv" style="display: none">
    popup contents...
</div>
<iframe id='popupSupporter-iframe' tabindex='-1' frameborder='0' style='display: block;
    position: absolute; z-index: -1; border: 0px none transparent; opacity: 0; top: auto;
    left: auto; width: auto; height: auto;'></iframe>
```

And in the script portion where you declare your dialog:

```
$('#popupDiv').dialog({
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var myDialogIFrame = $('#popupSupporter-iframe');
        var myDialog = $('#popupDiv').dialog("widget");
        myDialogIFrame.css("z-index", "10");
        var left = myDialog.offset().left + 'px';
        var top = myDialog.offset().top + 'px';
        var height = (myDialog.height() + 15) + 'px';
        var width = (myDialog.width() + 15) + 'px';
        $(myDialogIFrame).css("left", left).css("top", top).css("height", height).css("width", width);
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $('#popupSupporter-iframe').css("z-index", "-1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a floating div of the same size as the dialog.  It will be above the silverlight plugin.  You'll also need code to dismiss the div when the dialog is closed.

The dialog will be part of the div and therfore float above it above the silverlight.

Comment: Could you give a rough example of how to do this (I'm not particularly experienced in web development yet)?  I tried to google it, but couldn't find a helpful example.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following values for background and windowless attributes for the silverlight application worked for me :)

```
<param name="background" value="transparent" /> 
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```